# A pendulum in a superfluid

Tags: drag, oscillators, viscosity, dissipation, superfluidity

Imagine to submerge a pendulum in a supefluid. Of course we assume an ideal pendulum, whose joint does not freeze or deteriorate due to the extremely low temperature. We also assume the superfluid to be at zero temperature, so we can neglect its normal component.

What happens to its oscillations? Are they somehow damped? Or do they keep a constant amplitude?

In other words: can some energy be transferred from the pendulum to the superfluid (for example, thanks to the excitation of sound waves in the superfluid)?

Answer (score 14):

If the pendulum is fully submerged (and the velocity of the sphere is sufficiently small) then the flow around the sphere is Stokes flow, and the drag is proportional to viscosity. As a result there is no drag in a zero temperature superfluid. If the sphere is only partially submerged, then it can excite surface waves which take away energy. This setup is not completely academic — torsion pendulums have been used to measure the viscosity of liquid helium.

Further remarks:

1. The drag is described by Stokes formula $F=6\pi \eta RV$, where $\eta$ is the viscosity of the normal fluid, $R$ is the radius of the sphere, and $v$ is the velocity relative to the fluid. Drag vanishes if $\eta$ vanishes, or the normal density vanishes.
2. If the sphere is only partially submerged then there is a free surface and Stokes solution does not apply. Indeed, more generally, d'Alembert's paradox does not apply. An object will generate a bow wave in an inviscid fluid, and this leads to drag.
3. Every superfluid has a critical velocity. If the velocity of the object exceeds that velocity, then superfluidity breaks down, even at very small temperature.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please further comment on why if the sphere is only partially submerged, then it can excite surface waves? In addition: what happens, in the fully-submerged case, if the pendulum velocity is not sufficiently small?

Comment: Stokes flow? Stokes flow is the type of flow where viscosity is dominant and the inertial forces negligible. The almost potential flow in the superfluid component is the opposite of that. The normal viscous component may behave Stokes-like or not depending on the Reynolds number - as any other fluid.

Comment: But if you go to the low temperature limit and zero viscosity limit, than you should look at the potential flow, not the Stokes flow.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава The Stokes solution for flow around a sphere is potential flow. For zero viscosity there is no drag (this is sometimes called d'Alembert's paradox). For small $\eta$ we get Stokes famous result $F=6\pi\eta Rv$.

Comment: They have completely different boundary conditions. One Dirichlet, the other Neumann. And the vorticity is nonzero in Stokes flow while the potential flow is irrotational.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Stokes result is right, but the expansion in small Reynolds number is subtle (it is known to be singular perturbation theory). There are two issues: At large distance you cannot neglect the non-linear advection term. This was solved by Osseen, using singular perturbation theory. The other issue is that at short distance $\eta$ changes the boundary conditions. This was solved by Prandtl.

Comment: The stokes Result is completely fine - but for creeping flow, where viscous forces prevail over inertial forces. Small viscosity regime is the exact opposite, here the  inertial forces prevail. Doing the limit of eta -> 0 of the creeping flow result is just nonsense. The nonlinear term is tricky, but for potential flow it is fine, because the flow is irrotational.

Comment: The Stokes flow cannot be a potential flow for the simple reason that it is not irrotational. One cannot express the velocity vector as a gradient of a scalar potential unless the curl of the velocity vector is zero.

Comment: Even with zero viscosity, are there not compressive waves that dissipate energy from the pushing action of the pendulum?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава 1) Somehow we have drifted a long way from the original Q. The drag on a sphere in a superfluid is $F=6\pi \eta Rv$, where $\eta$ is the viscosity of the normal component. It vanishes as $\eta$ or $v\to 0$, and if there is no normal component. 2) The naive limit $\eta\to 0$ gives the correct result for an inviscid fluid, in which there is no drag (d'Alembert's paradox). However, the limit is subtle, because the Stokes formula is indeed the leading term in $Re=R\rho v/\eta$. 3) In a superfluid you might worry about exciting superfluid turbulence, but that requires $v>v_c$

Comment: I quote the comment by @RC_23. Are there compressive waves that dissipate energy from the pushing action of the pendulum?

Comment: @RC_23 I think that's true. The motion of the pendulum is accelerated, and in principle it can generate sound and shear waves. However, the frequency would typically very low, and I would guess that this not an efficient mechanism.

Comment: So in principle the oscillations of the pendulum are damped, and the associated energy is converted into sound and shear waves?

Comment: @AndreaPaco Yes, I think so